# qt model/view: how qt knows when to run default signal handlers, if I've reimplemented event handlers?

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, gtk, pyqt

I've got a general question on qt design.

Say, I created a custom classes, impelementing `QAbstractTableModel` and `QTableView` class. I've re-implemented event handlers in `View`, such as `mousePressed`, `mouseRelease` etc.

Still Qt's `View` manages to perform some of its default functionality: it still responds to mouse clicks and movements on cells by changing selection, thus it somehow fires `selectionModel` "built-in" signals, though I didn't ask it to. It still resizes columns, if I drag on cell borders etc. What's the mechanism that triggers those "buit-in, default slots" and how can I disable some parts of it? E.g. if I want to disable default behavior of `selectionModel` or default resize?

For the sake of comparison, in `gtk+` there's a concept of default per-class signal handler, which is a function, by default connected to its signal and called prior or after your custom per-class or per-object signal handlers, depending on parameters you set. You can disable it from your custom slot, if you want to and thoroughly control behavior of e.g. resize or selection.

Is Qt opaque in this place and provides customization via its interface functions only? My question is particularly related to `pyqt`. Please ask for clarification, if I'm too vague.

Answer (score 1):

The event handlers that you refer to are used to *listen* to events, not to filter them. You can't override any events in them, since they don't have a return value: there's no way to inform subsequent event processing that you don't wish it to run.

To *filter* events, you must reimplement the `event` method, and invoke the base class's implementation on events that you do not wish to filter.

In Qt, event handling is done per-object, and you can install external objects as event filters on any other object. An object receives the events in its `event` method. The `QObject` class implements this method and invokes the `timerEvent` method. The `QWidget` class reimplements this method and invokes the widget-specific `xxxEvent` methods. And so on. All of those classes still process some events internally. Those are the per-class handlers that you speak of.

Comment: Kuba Ober, thanks for answering. I've read some docs and just implemented an empty `event` function in my `QTableView` as you suggested: `def event(self, event): return False` (or `return True`, it doesn't affect the result). As you see, I didn't invoke any base class implementations of event handlers. Still, all the default functionality of QTableView is present: it responds to selecting cells with mouse, resizes cells, redraws etc. Why? I think, it shouldn't :)